# How to I send a response back from Express Route performing a req.write()?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am working with TextBroker's API through XML and having to write the data what feel pretty out of the norm than working with a RESTful API setup.

```
exports.getPendingOrders = (req, res) => {
  genCrypt()
    .then(encryptedAuth => {
      let requestEnvelope = `
    <soapenv:Envelope 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
      xmlns:urn="urn:budgetOrderService">\n   

      <soapenv:Header/>\n   
        <soapenv:Body>\n      
          <urn:create soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">\n\t    
            <salt xsi:type="xsd:string">${encryptedAuth.salt}</salt>\n         
            <token xsi:type="xsd:string">${
              encryptedAuth.token
            }</token>\n         
            <budget_key xsi:type="xsd:string">${
              config.budgetKey
            }</budget_key>\n         
            <category xsi:type="xsd:positiveInteger">1</category>\n         
            <title xsi:type="xsd:string">TEST from API 49</title>\n         
            <description xsi:type="xsd:string"><![CDATA[Nothing much<h1></h1>]]></description>\n         
            <min_words xsi:type="xsd:positiveInteger">1</min_words>\n         
            <max_words xsi:type="xsd:positiveInteger">100</max_words>\n         
            <classification xsi:type="xsd:positiveInteger">4</classification>\n         
            <working_time xsi:type="xsd:positiveInteger">2</working_time>\n         
            <author xsi:type="xsd:positiveInteger">756</author>\n         
            <note xsi:type="xsd:string">Nothing</note>\n         
            <deadline xsi:type="xsd:date"></deadline>\n      
          </urn:create>\n   
        </soapenv:Body>\n
      </soapenv:Envelope>
    `;
      return requestEnvelope;
    })
    .then(envelope => {
      var options = {
        method: "POST",
        hostname: "api.textbroker.com",
        path: "/Budget/budgetOrderService.php",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/xml",
          "cache-control": "no-cache"
        }
      };

      const request = http.request(options, function(res) {
        var chunks = [];

        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        // res.on("end", function() {
        //   console.log(body.toString());
        // });
      });

      request.write(envelope);


    });
};
```

Everything seems to function in terms of the generating of the salt and getting things out of my config. I can add in a `res.on('end')` and console log the body of `chunks` but I am wanting to send the data back to the front end so I can do something with it.

How exactly does one accomplish that?

Comment: So you want to wait for the http request to finish before you send something back to the client?

Comment: @goto1 - exactly when I get the res.on('end') I would like to return that to the original (req, res) and send it back to the client side so I can display a success message for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest turning your http request into a promise, like the following:

```js
function saveData(options) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    http.request(options, function(res) {
      var chunks = []

      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk)
      })
      res.on('end', function() {
        // the whole response has been received, so call `resolve` here

        const data = chunks.toString() // or whatever you want to pass back
        resolve(data)
      })
    })
      .on('error', err => { 
        reject(err)    
      })
  })
}
```

Then, in your code, you can call this function like so:

```js
exports.getPendingOrders = (req, res) => {
  genCrypt()
    .then(encryptedAuth => { ... })
    .then(envelope => {
      var options = { ... }

      return saveData(options)
    })
    .then(result => {
      // send it however you need it to the client
      // as an example, I am sending it as JSON

      res.status(200).json({ 
        data: result 
      })
    })
}
```

This way, you're going to get the result from your http call before calling `res.json()` and sending back the response.

---

I can't quite figure out from your code how `envelope` is being used or why you're doing `request.write(envelope)` if you're trying to send (to the client) the data that you get from the http request, but this should give you an idea.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. This should work and was the direction I originally thought I would have to go. I am writing a XML envelope (has to generate a salt / hash each time) and then send it to TextBroker's API.